# How to obtain the content between a tag and it's ending in HTML using python' beautiful soup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a HTML line as follows:

```
<span class="cd__headline-text">Is this model too thin for Yves Saint Laurent? </span>
```

I would like to extract the title i.e. "Is this model too thin for Yves Saint Laurent?" from this HTML line. How can I obtain any content between

```
<tag> and </tag>.
```

I am not really familiar with regex.

Comment: Please do look at the documentation, this is a *very basic task* that is covered both in the [quickstart](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#quick-start), in the [*Navigating the Tree* section](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string) and in the [*Output* section](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your element contains *only* text, use the [`.string` attribute](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string):

```
headline = soup.find(class_='cd__headline-text')
print(headline.string)
```

If there are other tags contained, you can either get all the text contained in the current element and further, or only get specific text from the current element.

The [`element.get_text()` function](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) will recurse and gather all strings in element and child elements, concatenating them with your string of choice (defaulting to the empty string) and with or without whitespace stripping.

To get only specific strings, you can either iterate over the [`.strings` or `.stripped_strings` generators](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#strings-and-stripped-strings), or use the [element contents](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children) to access all contained elements, then pick out instances of the `NavigableString` type.

Demo with your sample:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> markup = '<span class="cd__headline-text">Is this model too thin for Yves Saint Laurent? </span>'
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(markup)
>>> headline = soup.find(class_='cd__headline-text')
>>> print headline.string
Is this model too thin for Yves Saint Laurent? 
>>> print list(headline.strings)
[u'Is this model too thin for Yves Saint Laurent? ']
>>> print list(headline.stripped_strings)
[u'Is this model too thin for Yves Saint Laurent?']
>>> print headline.get_text()
Is this model too thin for Yves Saint Laurent? 
>>> print headline.get_text(strip=True)
Is this model too thin for Yves Saint Laurent?
```

and with an additional element added:

```
>>> markup = '<span class="cd__headline-text">Is this model <em>too thin</em> for Yves Saint Laurent? </span>'
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(markup)
>>> headline = soup.find(class_='cd__headline-text')
>>> headline.string is None
True
>>> print list(headline.strings)
[u'Is this model ', u'too thin', u' for Yves Saint Laurent? ']
>>> print list(headline.stripped_strings)
[u'Is this model', u'too thin', u'for Yves Saint Laurent?']
>>> print headline.get_text()
Is this model too thin for Yves Saint Laurent? 
>>> print headline.get_text(' - ', strip=True)
Is this model - too thin - for Yves Saint Laurent?
>>> headline.contents
[u'Is this model ', <em>too thin</em>, u' for Yves Saint Laurent? ']
>>> from bs4 import NavigableString
>>> [el for el in headline.children if isinstance(el, NavigableString)]
[u'Is this model ', u' for Yves Saint Laurent? ']
```

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I was looking for. The .string utility. Thanks a ton! :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using regular expressions, you should use some html parser like BeautifulSoup. You can also use etree library with xpath for complicated use cases.

Still, if you want to use regex -

Regular Expression is a Domain-Specific Language that makes string parsing and processing a lot more easier. Although, some people may disagree regular expressions provide much elegant solutions to problem, that looping over string could ever be.-

```
import re
html_string = '<span class="cd__headline-text">Is this model too thin for Yves Saint Laurent? </span>'
regex = re.compile(r'(?<=>).*(?=<)')
result = regex.findall(html_string)[0]
```

In this regex, I am using look-ahead and look-behind of regular expressions.
As far as learning regular expressions is concerned, it takes rather considerable amount of time. I recommend going through some good tutorial or some book on regex.

Comment: This is tagged BeautifulSoup, where the HTML is *already parsed* and can provide direct access to this information.

Comment: He wanted to know about regex to do this, so I told him. Anyway, I have changed my answer.

Comment: They mentioned they don't know how to use regex, but nowhere else do they mention wanting to use it. They do mention that they use BeautifulSoup.